# Eclipse is creating an old folder instead of using the new one

Tags: eclipse, directory, settings

I used to have Eclipse in a folder but then I decided to move the folder for Eclipse into a different folder. I deleted the old folder because I no longer needed it. Now Eclipse creates the old folder it used to be located in every time I start Eclipse.

Just to be clear: Eclipse is in folder "eclipse stuff" which got moved from folder A to folder B (both are on the Desktop) and folder A got deleted and now when Eclipse is opened it creates "Desktop\A\eclipse stuff\" with a sequence of folders within it.

My best guess is it is storing default settings in there (based on the names of the things in the folders) and that the directory it stores these "default settings" in is somewhere in Eclipse's settings. I don't know what settings it would be in. How can I change this setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch the workspace. `File` -> `Switch Workspace` -> `other` and choose the new folder. Restarting should preserve the new default workspace. If not, you can also delete old workspace locations in Eclipse setting: `Window` -> `Preferences` => `General` -> `Startup and Shutdown` -> `Workspaces` contains a list of all known workspaces. You can delete it there.

Comment: i have the same problem, but with an eclipse runtime application that gets started when debugging eclipse plugins. i've gone through the config.ini files, the workspace settings. i also deleted the complete runtime-Application folder. so somehow there is a setting somewhere left that i have missed?

Comment: No clue... Sorry.